# How to improve regex?

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression which will match characters: `a-z A-Z 0-9 .!$%&-_@#` without whitespace and in any possible order but my knowledge of regular expression is well lets say closer to 0 than expert. And there need to be at least 1 digit, 1 special character and 1 letter.

What i was able to make on my own:

```
[\S\w\.!$%&-_@#][^ ]{6,}
```

But well I'm not sure it'll work as I assumed.

**Question:**

How can I make this to match entire word not only part of it?

**Edit:**
I've tested it and it's not meet that:

> And there need to be at least 1 digit, 1 special character and 1 letter.

**Examples:**

not matching:

`aS1@.&%~+`

`asd dfgf`

`axf1345`

`1s4%z_-@#$ .!$%&-_@#`

correct:

`a1S#@%._`

`1aCF3%&`

`Abloct2$`

**@anubhava answer:**

`^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[_.!$%&@#-])[\w.!$%&@#-]{6,}$`

Comment: add anchors `^` and `$` with `mulltiline` flag

Comment: `\S` will include everything not whitespace = the rest of Unicode.

Comment: @nhahtdh do you suggest that I need to change `\S` to `a-zA-Z`?

Comment: @harry180: Just remove it, since `\w` already covers `a-zA-Z0-9_`

Comment: @harry180: Add some examples of valid and invalid matches.

Comment: How are you going to use this? Validate a whole string to match the regex? Or find matches in a string?

Comment: @nhahtdh well string which will came from somewhere will be matched against this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[_.!$%&@#-])[\w.!$%&@#-]{6,}$
```

- `(?=.*?[0-9])` is a lookahead to ensure there is at least one digit
- `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` is a lookahead to ensure there is at least one alphabet
- `(?=.*?[.!$%&@#-])` is a lookahead to ensure there is at least one special character

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fT2iU1/5)

Comment: I think the `.*?` should be `[\w.!$%&@#-]*`, otherwise "a1 #" will match.

Comment: Oh, so at any position in the line? I read the Q as being consecutive.

Comment: @anubhava now this regex does not make sure there is 6+ characters in provided string. To make it correct: `^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[_.!$%&@#-])[\w.!$%&@#-]{6,}+$`

Answer (score 0):

```
/[0-9a-zA-Z\$%&]+/
```

try this see details following link (middle section on the page) [regex details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)